# KnockoutJS Add Dynamic Columns

Tags: knockout.js

Trying to add multiple rows of teachers and columns of assistants at run time and I've based my core design so far on Ryan Neimeyer's example code which I've adapted to this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/3qLBL/. My latest update attempt is at http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/5E9HJ/ where I tried to add columns by creating a new instance of assistants, but all the checkboxes are bound to the same element, so every time I check one box, all are checked in the column. Here's my new attempt at trying to add assistants:

```
// new way - reuses same instance of Assistant for all rows
addAsst: function() {
    this.asstColumns.push(new Assistant(this.selectedAsst(), $('#assistants option:selected').text(), false, "0%", this.newFTE(), this.newType()));

    this.removeAsst(this.selectedAsst());  // remove the assistant from dropdown
    this.selectedAsst("0");                // reset the dropdown to "Select One..."
}
```

Clearly, I need to be able to add a new/unique instance of the Assistant to each Teacher row, but I believe that breaks my design. If it helps, I'll never have more than 7 assistants and always at least one. I was thinking another strategy could be to build out 7 assistant columns and maybe even make the ones that haven't had an assistant added by invisible, but I'm also struggling with how to update existing observable arrays. Here's the old way I tried adding assistants, where I simply added text from the Assistant dropdown that wasn't linked to an instance of new Assistant() like it is in the updated version. But, neither work like they should, since they need to be bound to an observable that updates when user clicks them.

```
// old way - creates new asst, but doesn't use it and doesn't bind anything        
addAsst: function() {
    var asst = new Assistant(this.selectedAsst(), $('#assistants option:selected').text(), this.newFTE(), this.newType());
    this.columns.push({property: $('#assistants option:selected').text(), 
    display: $('#assistants option:selected').text(), readonly: false });

    this.removeAsst(this.selectedAsst());   // remove the assistant from dropdown
    this.selectedAsst("0");                 // reset the dropdown to "Select One..."
}
```

TIA, Steve

Comment: I would like to help. Can you break you requirement in small chunks and later you can add them up.

Comment: Updated question to ask just how to add the assistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<comedian>
```

Well, almost a month has went by and since you worthless stack exchange "experts" and "gurus" wouldn't answer my question, I was forced to take it upon myself and learn KnockoutJS. So, I'm answering my own question, and it's probably a better answer than you would have given me anyway. But to the supposed "experts" and "gurus" I'm issuing a challenge - improve the design. Let's see if you live up to the hype. :)

```
</comedian>
```

As an aside, in my real application, the assistant class has several other attributes assigned to it, so that's why I made an AsstCol class. AsstCol is really a cell-level instance, and maybe it could/should be named AsstCell, but whatever. It's part of the teacher's Asst column too, but that's the biggest question mark in the app, but it is nonetheless functional.

View:

```
<table>
    <tr style="color:white; background-color:grey">
    <td></td>
    <!-- ko foreach: columns -->
    <td colspan="2" data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: teachers">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: asstCols -->
        <td class="cellLeft"><input data-bind="checked: isChecked, click: $root.updatePercentage" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="cellRight" data-bind="text: accounting.toFixed(percentage(), 0) + '%'"></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table class="reset">
    <tr>
    <td>Teacher:</td>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;">
        <select data-bind="
        options: availableTeachers,
        optionsText: 'name',
        value: selectedTeacher">
        </select>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;"><button data-bind="click: addTeacher">Add Teacher</button></td>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;"><button data-bind="click: addAsst">Add Assistant</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<ul data-bind="foreach: teachers">
    <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: asstCols">
        <li>
         <span data-bind="text: asstName"></span> :  <span data-bind="text: percentage"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

</ul>

<!-- <textarea style="width:620px; height:300px;" data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></textarea> -->
```

View Model:

```
// methods
var Teacher = function (id, name, asstCols) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.asstCols = ko.observableArray(asstCols).extend({ rateLimit: 0 });  // trigger just one re-evaluation of computed observable
};

var AsstCol = function (id, asstName, isChecked, percentage) {
    this.id = id;
    this.asstName = ko.observable(asstName);
    this.isChecked = ko.observable(isChecked);
    this.percentage = ko.observable(percentage);
};

var Assistant = function (id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
};

var viewModel = function (teachers, assistants, columnList) {
    var self = this;
    self.teachers = ko.observableArray(teachers).extend({ rateLimit: 0 });
    self.columns = ko.observableArray();

    // set initial columns
    for (var index in columnList) {
    self.columns.push(columnList[index].asstName());
    };

    self.assistants = ko.observableArray(assistants).extend({ rateLimit: 0 });
    self.selectedTeacher = ko.observable("0");
    self.availableTeachers = ko.observableArray([
    new Teacher(5, "Doug", [{}]),
    new Teacher(6, "Kevin", [{}])
    ]);

    // methods
    // passes current item as the first parameter
    self.updatePercentage = function (asstCol) {
    var totalChecked = 0, percentage = 0;

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teachers(), function (teacher) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.columns().length; i++) {
        if (teacher.asstCols()[i].id == asstCol.id) {
            if (teacher.asstCols()[i].isChecked()) {
            totalChecked++;
            break;
            }
        }
        }
    });

    percentage = 100 / totalChecked;

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teachers(), function (teacher) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.columns().length; i++) {
        if (teacher.asstCols()[i].id == asstCol.id) {
            if (teacher.asstCols()[i].isChecked())
            teacher.asstCols()[i].percentage(percentage);
            else
            teacher.asstCols()[i].percentage(0);
        }
        }
    });

    return true;    // return default browser behavior to allow check/uncheck
    };

    // operations
    self.addTeacher = function () {
    self.teachers.push(new Teacher(ko.unwrap(self.selectedTeacher().id), ko.unwrap(self.selectedTeacher().name), undefined));

    // add each of the asst columns
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.assistants(), function (assistant) {
        self.teachers()[self.teachers().length - 1].asstCols.push(new AsstCol(assistant.id, assistant.name, false, 0));
    });
    self.teachers.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name.toLowerCase() == b.name.toLowerCase() ? 0 : (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
    });
    self.columns.sort();
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teachers(), function (teacher) {
        teacher.asstCols.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.asstName().toLowerCase() == b.asstName().toLowerCase() ? 0 : 
        (a.asstName().toLowerCase() < b.asstName().toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
        });
    });

    // remove teacher from dropdown and reset the selection
    self.availableTeachers.remove(function (item) { return item.id == ko.unwrap(self.selectedTeacher().id); });
    self.selectedTeacher("0");
    };
    self.addAsst = function () {
    self.assistants.push(new Assistant(22, "Abby"));
    self.assistants.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name.toLowerCase() == b.name.toLowerCase() ? 0 : (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
    });
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teachers(), function (teacher) {
        teacher.asstCols.push(new AsstCol(22, "Abby", false, 0));
    });
    self.columns.push("Abby");        
    };
};

var initialTeachers = [
    new Teacher(1, "Jeff", [
    new AsstCol(20, "Susie", true, 50),
    new AsstCol(21, "Bobby", true, 33)
    ]),
    new Teacher(2, "Joe", [
    new AsstCol(20, "Susie", false, 0),
    new AsstCol(21, "Bobby", true, 33)
    ]),
    new Teacher(3, "Josie", [
    new AsstCol(20, "Susie", true, 50),
    new AsstCol(21, "Bobby", true, 33)
    ])
];

var initialAssistants = [
    new Assistant(21, "Bobby"),
    new Assistant(20, "Susie")
];

var vm = new viewModel(initialTeachers, initialAssistants, initialTeachers[0].asstCols());
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 2px;
}
.reset td, th {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.cellLeft {
    border: 0;
    border-left:solid 1px black;
    border-bottom:solid 1px black;
    padding:1px 1px 1px 4px;
}
.cellRight {
    border: 0;
    border-right:solid 1px black;
    border-bottom:solid 1px black;
    padding:1px; padding:1px 4px 1px 1px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/2ymf5cyx/37/)